# $fg[cyan]~$reset_color $(git_prompt_info) Mac Os terminal problem

Tags: macos, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm looking for an answer about a problem that is happening in my terminal mac. I research a lot of answers and none solved my problem.

I'm getting this message when i open my prompt:

```
Last login: Tue Jul 20 14:17:28 on ttys001

➜  $fg[cyan]~$reset_color $(git_prompt_info)
```

I've tried to reinstall, change .zshrc file, etc.

This is my .oh-my-zsh/themes/robbyrussell.zsh-theme

```
PROMPT="%(?:%{$fg_bold[green]%}➜ :%{$fg_bold[red]%}➜ )"

PROMPT+=' %{$fg[cyan]%}%c%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info)'

ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX="%{$fg_bold[blue]%}git:(%{$fg[red]%}"

ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX="%{$reset_color%} "

ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DIRTY="%{$fg[blue]%}) %{$fg[yellow]%}✗"

ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_CLEAN="%{$fg[blue]%})"
```

Sorry for my bad explaining I'm brand in this area
Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
PROMPT+=' %{$fg[cyan]%}%c%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info)'
```

does not make sense. You are using single quotes, which prohibit parameter expansion. Use double quotes instead.

Comment: You're right lol, idk why it happened. Thank you a lot!